# Creating Rails 4 Form with Join Table Metadata

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Very new Rails 4 developer here. I've got a form where a user is creating Exercises. Exercises can have many Equipment, and Equipment can be optional( think push-up stands for doing push-ups ). I store this "optional" field on the join table exercise_equipment.

I cannot get the parameters to actually send through the values of the collection element that I pick. See below for the model, view, controller, and parameters.

Here are the attributes/relationships of my models:

```
# id        :integer
# name      :string
# is_public :boolean
Exercise
    has_many :exercise_equipment
    has_many :equipment, :through => :exercise_equipment
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercise_equipment


# id           :integer
# exercise_id  :integer
# equipment_id :integer
# optional     :boolean
ExerciseEquipment
    belongs_to :exercise
    belongs_to :equipment
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :equipment


# id   :integer
# name :string
Equipment
    has_many :exercise_equipment
    has_many :exercises, :through => :exercise_equipment
```

Here are some (maybe) relevant controller methods:

```
def new
  @exercise = Exercise.new
  @exercise.exercise_equipment.build
end

def create
  @exercise = Exercise.new( exercise_params )
  if @exercise.save
    redirect_to @exercises
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @exercise = Exercise.find( params[:id] )
end

def update
  @exercise = Exercise.find( params[:id] )
  if @exercise.update_attributes( exercise_params )
    redirect_to @exercises
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def exercise_params
  params.require( :exercise ).permit(
    :name,
    :is_public,
    exercise_equipment_attributes: [
      :id,
      :optional,
      equipment_attributes: [
        :id,
        :name
      ],
    ]
  )
end
```

This is my shot at creating a view to do what I want:

**exercises/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @exercise do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit "New Exercise" %>
<% end %>
```

**exercises/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.check_box :is_public %> Public

<%= f.fields_for( :exercise_equipment ) do |eef|
  <%= eef.fields_for( :equipment ) do |ef|
    ef.collection_select :id, Equipment.all, :id, :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= eef.check_box :is_optional %> Optional
<% end %>
```

When I put all of this together and submit an update to an already-existing exercise, the values all go through the params hash, but aren't changed to the new values I've selected...

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"[checkbox]",
  "authenticity_token"=>"[token]",
  "exercise"=>{
    "name"=>"Test", 
    "is_public"=>"1", 
    "exercise_equipment_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{
        "equipment_attributes"=>{
          "id"=>"1"
        }, 
        "optional"=>"1", 
        "id"=>"2" 
      } 
    } 
  },
  "commit"=>"Save Exercise",
  "id"=>"1" 
}
```

If you can help me out, I'd be super appreciative. Just let me know if you need any more information and I can provide it.

**EDIT**

Here is the state of the database before updating:

```
postgres@=>db=# select id, name, is_public from exercises;
 id | name | is_public 
----+------+-----------
  2 | Test | t
(1 row)

Time: 61.279 ms
postgres@=>db=# select id, exercise_id, equipment_id, optional from exercise_equipment;
 id | exercise_id | equipment_id | optional 
----+-------------+--------------+----------
  2 |           2 |            1 | t
(1 row)

Time: 58.819 ms
postgres@=>db=# select id, name from equipment where id = 1;
 id |    name     
----+-------------
  1 | Freeweights
(1 row)
```

I then go to the update route for that exercise, select a different equipment from the collection, and submit the form. I get the following Rails Console results:

```
Started PATCH "/exercises/system-test" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 23:48:18 -0400
Processing by ExercisesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PsbbUPSCiIew2Fd22Swn+K4PmLjwNDCrDdwXf9YBcm8=", "exercise"=>{"name"=>"Test", "is_public"=>"1", "exercise_equipment_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"equipment_attributes"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "optional"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}}}, "commit"=>"Save Exercise", "id"=>"system-test"}
  Exercise Load (60.5ms)  SELECT  "exercises".* FROM "exercises"  WHERE "exercises"."slug" = 'system-test'  ORDER BY "exercises"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (57.3ms)  BEGIN
  ExerciseEquipment Load (76.2ms)  SELECT "exercise_equipment".* FROM "exercise_equipment"  WHERE "exercise_equipment"."exercise_id" = $1 AND "exercise_equipment"."id" IN (2)  [["exercise_id", 2]]
  Equipment Load (59.1ms)  SELECT  "equipment".* FROM "equipment"  WHERE "equipment"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (60.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  Exercise Exists (60.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "exercises"  WHERE ("exercises"."name" = 'Test' AND "exercises"."id" != 2 AND "exercises"."user_id" = 10) LIMIT 1
   (64.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/exercises/system-test
Completed 302 Found in 590ms (ActiveRecord: 580.0ms)


Started GET "/exercises/system-test" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-12 23:48:19 -0400
Processing by ExercisesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"system-test"}
  Exercise Load (64.1ms)  SELECT  "exercises".* FROM "exercises"  WHERE "exercises"."slug" = 'system-test'  ORDER BY "exercises"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Equipment Load (58.7ms)  SELECT "equipment".* FROM "equipment" INNER JOIN "exercise_equipment" ON "equipment"."id" = "exercise_equipment"."equipment_id" WHERE "exercise_equipment"."exercise_id" = $1  [["exercise_id", 2]]
  Rendered exercises/show.html.erb within layouts/application (122.7ms)
  User Load (60.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 10  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (61.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_alerts.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 264ms (Views: 21.3ms | ActiveRecord: 240.8ms)
```

Comment: Is that the only output from your web server? It should tell you what it's trying to do, i.e. SQL query, save, etc.

Comment: I've included the full PATCH trace from my server logs in an edit, along with my initial database state. Thanks so much for taking a look!

Comment: In your nested form, its this |e_form|, but you call `ef.collection_select` - shouldn't it be `e_form.collection_select` ?

Comment: Hmmm. I do something similar in a repair-ticket/parts-used scenario. When I load a service ticket and change the parts used it does some `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements to make the changes in the DB. I'm not seeing any here. I'm a little rusty, but I know with multiple checkboxes and updating you have to use some hidden fields in your form.

Comment: @Beartech thanks, I suppose I'll have to look into hidden fields.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised

Comment: @Beartech it's actually just the associations that don't update. The boolean fields update correctly.

Comment: ACK! Sorry, it's late. I misunderstood what you wrote. You want to generate a new relation by using the nested form, right? Triple nested form is going to get complex. I'm gonna delete my comments since they don't add to the discussion.

Comment: Your form_for helper should have @exercise. Typo?

Comment: @TiagoFarias Just an error in translation, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make sure you define your associations correctly.

Any `has_many` association should be defined with a *plural* name -

```
#app/models/exercise.rb
Class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exercise_equipments
    has_many :equipments, :through => :exercise_equipments

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercise_equipments
end

#app/models/exercise_equipment.rb
Class ExerciseEquipment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :exercise
   belongs_to :equipment
end

#app/models/equipment.rb
Class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :exercise_equipments
   has_many :exercises, through: :exercise_equipments
end
```

If you've already got it working, and are happy with what you've got, then I'd recommend keeping your current setup. However, you may wish to adopt the above for [convention's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) sake

*Edit* I see from the deleted answer that `Beartech` investigated this, and turns out Rails treats Equipment / Equipments as the same. Will be worth ignoring the above, but I'll leave it for future reference

---

**Params**

> I cannot get the parameters to actually send through the values of the
>   collection element that I pick. See below for the model, view,
>   controller, and parameters.

I think I get what you mean - you're looking to update the record, but it does not send through the updated parameters to your controller, hence preventing it from being updated.

Although I can't see any glaring problems, I would recommend the issue is that you're trying to populate the `exercise_id` of an `Exercise` object. You need to define it for the `exercise_equipment` object:

```
<%= f.fields_for :exercise_equipment do |eef| %>
   <%= eef.collection_select :equipment_id, Equipment.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= eef.check_box :is_optional %>
<% end %>
```

This will populate your `exercise_equipment` table as described here:

```
Time: 61.279 ms
postgres@=>db=# select id, exercise_id, equipment_id, optional from exercise_equipment;
 id | exercise_id | equipment_id | optional 
----+-------------+--------------+----------
  2 |           2 |            1 | t
(1 row)
```

Currently, you're populating the `Equipment` model with `equipment_id` - which won't work. Populating the model in that way will server to *create* a new record, not update the ones already created

---

**Extra Field**

> I want to have a link to add an additional equipment field when it is
>   clicked, similar to how Ryan Bates did it in this RailsCast, but the
>   helper method he writes( see "Show Notes" tab if you're not subscribed
>   to see the source ) seems to become substantially more complex when
>   dealing with the nested views shown in my code below. Any help in
>   dealing with this?

This a trickier mountain to overcome

Ryan uses quite an outdated method in this process (to pre-populate the link and then just let JS append the field). The "right" way is to build a new object & append the `fields_for` from ajax. Sounds tough? That's because it is :)

Here's how you do it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :exercises do
   collection do
       get :ajax_update #-> domain.com/exercises/ajax_update
   end
end

#app/models/exercise.rb
Class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.build
       exercise = self.new
       exercise.exercise_equipment.build
   end
end

#app/controllers/exercises_controller.rb
Class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @exercise = Exercise.build
   end

   def ajax_update
      @exercise = Exercise.build
      render "add_exercise", layout: false #> renders form with fields_for
   end
end

#app/views/exercises/add_exercise.html.erb
<%= form_for @exercise do |f| %>
   <%= render partial: "fields_for", locals: { form: f } %>
<% end %>

#app/views/exercises/_fields_for.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :exercise_equipment, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |eef| %>
    <%= eef.collection_select :equipment_id, Equipment.all, :id, :name  %>
    <%= eef.check_box :is_optional %>
<% end %>

#app/views/exercises/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @exercise do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "fields_for", locals: { form: f } %>
    <%= link_to "Add Field", "#", id: "add_field" %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#add_field", function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "exercises/ajax_update",
       success: function(data) {
          el_to_add = $(data).html()
          $('#your_id').append(el_to_add)
       }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what's going on in the javascript that you wrote? Also, is there a way to move it out of the application.js file and into an exercise-specific coffescript file?